# How to filter product with salable filter in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

In magento 1 ,

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1); // enabled
$products->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple');
//$products->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('1234')); //for testing purposes
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($products);
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);
$prodIds = $products->getAllIds();
```

I need to filter product collection with Is_salable() filter in magento2

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addSaleableFilterToCollection($products);
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);
```

How to do this in magento2?

```
$collection = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId) // Load Category Products by CategoryID
                ->getProductCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('color_family', array('eq' => $optionId))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any module or class for thie?

Comment: yes ...........

Answer (score 0):

Inject the **\Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock** to your construct function of your class:

```
protected $_stockFilter;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock $stockFilter
    ....
){
    $this->_stockFilter = $stockFilter; 
}
```

Then add the stock filter to your public function from where you will get the in stock product collection like below:

```
public function getProductCollection() {
    ..........
    $this->_stockFilter->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
    ..........
}
```

Comment: addInStockFilterToCollection-->Its check only stock Info ...But Is_salable check the Is_available(),  stock ..

Comment: This will return the instock products only? What do you want?

Comment: Also Check is product available for sale and Is_available()

Comment: its not working for MSI in magento 2.3

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the collection to get only products in stock with the flag for `has_stock_status_filter`:

```
$collection = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId)
                ->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', true);
```

This should work in Magento 2.3 and 2.4